# Meaning of ２浪してるんだ

Tags: meaning, manga

I want to know what ２浪してるんだ means, also I assume the "2" means that the kanji is repeated twice, right?

I thought the hiragana at the side is telling me how to read this kanji (へえ) but looking up on romajidesu.com I see that this kanji "on" reading is rō (ロウrō)

The sentence that is coming after that is 根性  あるねえ
[image]

Comment: Humorous hint: http://d2dcan0armyq93.cloudfront.net/photo/odai/400/1b3c0f0326185ed2ac2631b5ef59a0c9_400.jpg

Comment: 自身の経験から言うと、大学受験制度が日本のそれと大きく異なる国の人に、この浪人というコンセプトを説明するのは難しい。特に北米人。基本北米では誰も浪人しないから。

Comment: Try looking up 大学浪人...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for へえ that is at the side of 浪, it is not the *furigana* that tells how to read the kanji as you know, but it is the first part of the sentence. So, the whole sentence should be read like へえ ２浪してるんだ 根性あるねぇ.

**Edit:**
As for ２浪, it is also written as 二浪 and both are read as *ni-roh* or にろう. [２浪]{にろう} or [二浪]{にろう} means a person that has been "浪人｛ろうにん｝*rohnin*" for two consecutive years. The meaning of a ***rohnin*** is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C5%8Dnin). It is mainly used for the high school alumni who have failed twice in the entrance examination of the university/college that they desired to enter as is explained in another answer. Not so many but it is also used for those who have failed to find a job in a desired company. *Rohnin* seems to be a peculiar custom in Japan, but since it is an ordinary word for Japanese, please understand it as one of Japanese words and also Japanese customs to learn.

As for the manga, when I look at the resume, the person is a man and 27 years old. He is  going to take the employment exam (in this case, an interview for job) in order to get a job at his desired company.
In the manga, the interviewer knows that the job seeker failed twice in the entrance examination of the university he desired by reading the record of the resume, so the interviewer said to the job seeker admiringly that "2浪してるんだ 根性あるねぇ. *You experienced rohnin for two years, right? I know you have enough guts.*"

In general, if we fail in the employment examination of the company or government office we want to work for, we will give up them and work for another company and the like. However, if the person can not give up them, they will wait for one year by becoming *rohnin*s or １浪 and take the employment exam of them again in the next year. If they still fail in the exam, they will also become *rohnin*s or ２浪 and take the exam of them in the next year.

Comment: I wonder if people write failing the job exam on a resume. And I think companies in Japan recruit employees except new graduates all year. So I think it says about college entrance exams.

Comment: @YuuichiTam: 日本語で書きます。コメントありがとうございます。浪人と言えば大学受験のための浪人が普通ですね。異論ありません。漫画をよく見ますと大き‌​なビルの前に「最終面接会場」とあります。‌​大学入学で面接のある学校もたまにはありま‌​すが何度も行うことはありません。「最終」という言葉は２度目には普通使いません。２回目が最終なら「２次面接会場」となります。年齢は‌​２７です。就職のしかも面接を含め３次試験‌​以上ある狭き門の人気企業の最終面接と見ました。確かに履歴書に浪人とは書き‌​ません。私も、履歴書からは２７歳男性としか読んでおりません。浪人であることは面接官の推察です。面接による会話と書類とからその人物‌​の何者かを推察します。高卒の年と大学入学の年から大学入学２浪と言った可能性は十分あります。私は「就職浪人」と見ただけです。公務員や官製企業はいまでも年一度か二度の定期採用だと思います。選考回数の多い企業は、大人気企業で競争率が何十倍にもなるところです。浪人しても入りたいし、その企業愛をアピールして就職に漕ぎつけたい思う企業です。「へえ ２浪してるんだ 根性あるねぇ」という面接官からのコメントを引き出せただけでもこの受験生は半分合格です。今でもあなたの大学受験２浪を否定しませんが、試験はあくまでも就職試験会場であることは譲れません（笑）。

Comment: あの・・Tamさんも、（他の人もですが）これが job interview の場面であることはわかっていると思いますが。。job interview で、面接官が「君、二年大学浪人したの？根性あるねえ」と言ってると解釈してらっしゃるのではないでしょうか。。（履歴書を見たら何年大学浪人したかってすぐバレるので）

Answer (score 4):

We call the people who can enter university soon after graduating from high school 現役.

一浪 means "failing college entrance exams in the year of graduating from high school and retaking them a year later".

So 二浪 means "failing college entrance exams which he retook a year after graduating from high school and retaking them another year later", that is to say, it took him two years to enter university after graduating from high school.

Answer (score 2):

"Oh... you took two years to enter university. You are tough."

I guess this 根性あるねぇ has two feelings of the interviewer, seeing this situation only.

- You hardly ever give up on your goals.
- You are not a thoughtful type of person.(Irony)

Generally speaking, 浪人生 burden their parents in financial or mental aspect. So they study so hard during the year to pass exams, otherwise they change the goal. 二浪 indicates that this person did not care his parents in his deep mind.

To see his answer はい！ Kaizaki san does not seem to be even worried about the interviewer's irony. I think him to be an actually thoughtless, free-from-nervous type of guy.